# Fill in hole with too many faces and edges

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender and I'm trying to learn how to fill in the hole in the image below. [image]

I have searched on youtube, google and stackexchange on how to fill holes and all the solutions are either using looptools bridge or alt + F. This however do not work for the object I have since I am not able to select all the tiny pieces of edges. I managed to join the four parts into one object, now however I have been stuck for hours. Any idea on how to proceed and fill the hole?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think we are gong to have to see your Blend file. - It looks from the Moire patterns on the sides of those cylinders as if you have duplicate meshes in the same place. You can share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest maybe building the shape with less geometry and using the circle object with different radii first then upping the sibdivision later to get smoother results.

Maybe follow the following steps:
[image: Start with creating circles with the different radii to get the footprint yout would like]

[image: Remove extra verts]

[image: Merge the corresponding points at centre]

[image: Select all and create a face with 'f']

[image: Select Face and Extrude Upwards2]

[image: Crease edges if you need to subdivide using ctrl 'E']

[image: Add a subdivision surface to smooth out your result]

In general, I always like to model with less geometry and then refine later, less geometry means less you need to keep track of to get yourself a good result! Hope this helps at all :)

To Answer the question in your comment I would go about it like this:

[image]

So let's take this setup again without deleting the interior geometry of the circles.
[image]

Again we merge the corresponding verts.

[image]

Select following verts and create face

[image]

Close the faces of the circles by selecting the corresponding verts (CTRL click helps select verts in a line fast!)

[image]

Extrude all faces together

[image]

Lastly select the circle faces and extrude those once more to get the desired height! Hope this helps :)

Comment: Could you edit to explain how you went from stop 1 (the 4 circles) to step 2 (the basic outline)?

Comment: Sure! Added captions to the images but they didn't seem to come up >:(

step 1: Start by creating a circle object and duplicate the circle and use s to scale the circles until you create a rough outline of the shape you need.

step 2: Delete the extra vertices that don't make up your shape (x to delete) 

step 3: Select corresponding vertices that are almost overlapping and merge them using 'm' at centre

Step 4: Select all and press 'f' to create the face :)

Comment: This answer helped a lot! Thank you! I do however still have some issues. The hard part here is that the cylinders have different height where the height of the "link" between the cylinders have the same height as the cylinder with the larger radius. How would you take that into consideration?

Comment: Check out my edit, this should help you :)

Comment: It turned out great! Thank you so much!

Comment: No Problem! I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Selecting Loops can be useful.  I would create faces as follows:

1. Select a verticle segment on both sides where you want new edges, or select two adjacent vertices and "Select :: Loops :: Edge" to extend the selection:

[image]

2. The use the menu "Edge :: Bridge" to create the new edges
3. subdivide these edges "sufficiently" (you can always add a Smooth or Subdivision modifiers later).
4. same for other side of the destination face
5. In Edit-Edge mode, carefully select the corner edges of the target face
6. "Select :: Loops :: Edge" to extend the selection all the way around

[image]

7. use the menu "Vertex :: New Face" for these edges.

[image]

and you'll get this new face where the edges can be moved to sculpt into some curve.

[image]

8. do the same for the other (bottom) side

In terms of "sculpting" the new edge into some curve, you could select a set of vertices halfway in-between the left/right sides and proportionally move.  You can do this before or after adding the new faces.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the topology of your model is way too complex that it needs to be (I would say like a 1000% more maybe even more). You should try to keep the topology as simple as possible. If you need the model to be smooth you can alway right-click -> shade smooth or use a subdivision modifier. Second of all if you are trying to make it one continuos shape, this is not a way to do it. Joining the geometries into one object does not mean the geometries are actually connected (and with the topology you have it would be very hard to do so)

Anyway to your question. You can select a whole loopcut by holding alt + selecting you geometry. this way you woudn't have to click every single edge separately. you can also select one of the edges and while holding ctrl+shift select another one. This will select the shortest path needed to reach it.

[image]

First normal click, second alt+click, third ctrl+shift click

Now for the question about connecting faces. Alt+f is a shortcut for filling a face. That is possible only when you have a closed loop of edges that you want to fill with faces. I cannot really see whether the shape in the middle is closed or not as it overlaps with the cylinders but my guess is it is not. What you probably want to do is simple F shortcut. This creates a new face between selected geometries like so:

[image]

My guess is your geometry looks like this underneath the cylinders (though with much much more complex topology):
[image]

By combining info I gave you you'll simply do something like this:
[image]

I strongly recommend you to start over with much less topology as the geometry is simple enough to create from scratch and you won't run into troubles in the future with it. Personally I would create such shape from bezier curve. It is quite simple to manipulate with (you could do it with just a few control points) and you don't have tu worry about messing up topology.